# Tkinter window stopped updating

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I just started working on Tkinter with help of youtube. I tried to show Label in root window it showed, then button, it didnt work. Now it is not showing anything and root window is coming as empty whatever I do, that too in a fixed dimension.

```
from tkinter import *

root1 = Tk()

questionLabel = Label(root1, text="Hello World", fg="red")
questionLabel.pack

# submitButton = Button(root, text="Submit", fg="blue")
# submitButton.pack


root1.mainloop()
```

[image: Screenshot of code and Window created by Tkinter]

Python version: 3.9
VS Code version: 1.68.1

Comment: You have to actually call the `.pack()` method in order to make the widget visible.

Comment: Thank you very much you sir. I am very embarrassed for my stupidity :( I spent hours on this, and overlooked this small thing